# How can I solve this? I'm trying to get method in a constructor which will perform algebra on two numbers

Tags: javascript, methods, constructor

I'm trying to get method in a constructor which will perform algebra on two numbers but nothing is working

```js
function algebra() {
  a = prompt("enter");
  this.a = parseInt(a);

  b = prompt("enter");
  this.b = parseInt(b);

  function sum(a, b) {
    return (a + b);
  }

  function sub(a, b) {
    return (a - b);
  }

  function mul(a, b) {
    return (a * b);
  }

  function div(a, b) {
    return (a / b);
  }
}

var sum1 = new algebra();

console.log(sum1.sum);
```

Comment: You will need to add the methods to the `algerbra` `prototype`. Those methods should probably refer to `this.a` and `this.b`

Comment: or, using modern JS, [write a class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) (which still uses prototypes under the hood, you just don't need to write any code for explicitly working with prototypes and proto assignment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is because the way to call a `function` inside another `function` is to declare it on the same function. For example:

```
function foo() {
  function bar() {
    return "foo bar";
  }
}
```

The only way to call `bar()` is calling inside of `foo()`.

If you want to call a function that is inside another function you have to declare it as a variable that belongs to that function like this example:

```
function foo() {
  this.bar = function() {
    return "foo bar";
  }
}
```

With this approach you can do:

```
let foobar = new foo();

foobar.bar();
```

Another way of getting the same result is to use `class`.

```
class algebra {
  constructor(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }
  
  sum() {
    return (this.a + this.b);
  }
}
```

and

```
let sum1 = new algebra(4, 5);
sum1.sum(); // output 9
```

Here is your code working:

```js
// or simply do function algebra() {...} instead of let algebra = function() {...} both work
let algebra = function() {
  a = prompt("enter");
  this.a = parseInt(a);

  b = prompt("enter");
  this.b = parseInt(b);

  this.sum = function() {
    return (this.a + this.b);
  }

  this.sub = function() {
    return (this.a - this.b);
  }

  this.mul = function() {
    return (this.a * this.b);
  }

  this.div = function() {
    return (this.a / this.b);
  }
}

var sum1 = new algebra();
console.log(sum1.sum());
```

As the `method` is inside the `constructor` and the `variables` are at the `constructor` `scope`, you don't need to pass them when calling a `method`.

here is a working fiddle with both examples: http://jsfiddle.net/xpjwqf72/2/

Comment: I understood what you are trying to say, but isn't there a way to call a sum function from algebra constructor. If yes, please elaborate
Like I was trying to do in my code above! I was trying to make a constructor algebra and then calling method sum from the constructor

Comment: As it's pointed in my answer, you can achieve it using the 2nd example of `foo bar` where `this.bar` will be your `sum` function. I will update my answer to use snippet with what i think you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function algebra() {
  a = prompt("enter");
  this.a = parseInt(a);

  b = prompt("enter");
  this.b = parseInt(b);

  this.sum = function() {
    return (parseInt(a) + parseInt(b));
  }

  this.sub = function() {
    return (a - b);
  }

  this.mul = function() {
    return (a * b);
  }

  this.div = function() {
    return (a / b);
  }
  return this;
}

var sum1 = new algebra();

console.log(sum1.sum());
console.log(sum1.sub());
console.log(sum1.mul());
console.log(sum1.div());
```